# Getting an error in python that Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

enter image description here
import os
import sys

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
```

#this code giving an error that Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1

```
variable2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/hp/Desktop/NIFTY/WIPRO.csv")

frames = [variable2]
all = pd.concat(frames)
print(all)
```

#getting all the required columns from WIPRO.CSV

```
price_data = all [['Symbol','Date','Close','High','Low','Open','Volume']]
```

#applying on balance volume indicator on stock data

```
def on_balance_volume(df):

    i = 0
    OBV = [0]

    while i < df.index[-1]:
        if df.loc[i + 1, 'Close'] - df.loc[i, 'Close'] > 0:
            OBV.append(df.loc[i + 1, 'Volume'])
        if df.loc[i + 1, 'Close'] - df.loc[i, 'Close'] == 0:
            OBV.append(0)
        if df.loc[i + 1, 'Close'] - df.loc[i, 'Close'] < 0:
            OBV.append(-df.loc[i + 1, 'Volume'])
        i = i + 1
    OBV = pd.Series(OBV)
    OBV_ma = pd.Series(OBV.rolling(14, min_periods=14).mean(), name='OBV_' + str(14))
    df = df.join(OBV_ma)
    return df
obv_groups = price_data.groupby('Symbol').apply(on_balance_volume)
```

#python is pointing the lower line for the error when i am trying to save the result in my data frame

```
price_data['On_Balance_Volume'] = obv_groups.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: this is the error wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1

Comment: i do not know how to fix it help me

Comment: That is not the whole error message. Please post the full output you get after submitting this command and add it directly to your question.